# Nugetconfig packageSource not recognized by Sharp Develop in a local nugetconfig

Tags: nuget, sharpdevelop

I am struggeling to setup the packageSource based on a nuget config file that I placed in the same folder of the solution file. (described here: [nuget doku](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file))

The strange thing I noticed is that **Visual Studio 2013 recognizes my package** source and is showing it in the package manager GUI within Visual Studio.

**Sharp Develop is not recognizing it** and is only showing the default Nuget source.
So far I tried Sharp Develop version 4.4 and 5.0 beta.

Here is my example config file (nuget.config) in case you need it.

```
<configuration>
  <packageSource >
    <add key="Official Example FTP" value="\\test\test\..." />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="Official Example FTP" value="\\test\test\..." />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Please, does someone tried to accomplish what I was written above **with** Sharp Develop ?

Many thanks in advance.

Note: I am new to Nuget and cannot decide if this is a Sharp Develop issue and should be long to the sharp develop forum, therfore please dont downvote this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported in SharpDevelop. Package sources are currently only taken from the NuGet.config in the user's profile:

```
%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.config
```

Any package sources defined in a solution or project level NuGet.config file will not be picked up by SharpDevelop.

**Update 2014/05/18:**

SharpDevelop 5.0.0.4406 and above supports solution specific NuGet.config files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is the feature planned for some release of Sharp Develop in future ?

Comment: Since Visual Studio supports it then SharpDevelop should support it. So it will be added to SharpDevelop at some point.

Comment: Do you have any timeframe when this feature will be added ?

Comment: Sorry I do not have timeframe. I would need to look into what is required first.